# How Do i pass a file into a web method?

Tags: c#, file, file-upload, webmethod

I would like to pass a file into a [Webmethod] and once its inside, send it as an email attachment.

How would i go about doing this? I'm unsure where to start?

**FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName** and **FileUpload1.FileContent** are the 2 things i want to pass into my [webmethod].

My Problem is the **FileUpload1.FileContent**, because i can already send my **FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName** as a String

```
lblEmailSent.Text = Send.Sendemail(txtTo.Text, txtSubject.Text, txtbody.Text, FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName, FileUpload1.FileContent);
```

My Call Statement is underlined in blue and the two error given look like:

> **1)**The best overloaded method match for
>   'WebTestServiceApp.localhost.Service1.Sendemail(string, string,
>   string, string, WebTestServiceApp.localhost.Stream)' has some invalid
>   arguments
>
> **2)**Argument 5: cannot convert from 'System.IO.Stream' to
>   'WebTestServiceApp.localhost.Stream'

Please could someone show me how i can send **FileUpload1.FileContent** into a [Webmethod]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To see what i'm trying to do, check out my question :http://stackoverflow.com/q/10431928/1356321 This will let you see what code i have thus far.

Comment: IMO, the "correct" way to serialize and deserialize an `UploadFile` is... to not do that. If you need to pass a filename and data, then by all means do that - but that doesn't need `UploadFile`

Comment: Ok so how do i pass the FileUpload1.FileContent to the Webmethod???, I need to attach a file to an email so i need uploadfile

Comment: no, you need to send data; that does not need to be done via an `UploadFile`; a base-64 string (or `byte[]` if it works) would be much simpler

Comment: Ok how do i send data? i am reading up on base-64 and Byte[] how do i contvert a file into that? and is the conversion not called serializeing the data?

Comment: You have been no help at all, basically answered my question with [no] and have not redirected me in any helpful way? You neged my question with -1 point suggesting i have done no research effort, but i have 3 question asking for help of this same topic, and there is a link there to redirect you, its a very detailed question to something i do believe will be a easy answer its just something i don't understand. so thanks for no help the -1 will chase people who might help away!

Comment: which "you" are you referring to? The -1 is not by me, not that it matters. Do you expect me to apologise for stepping away from my PC for a moment? Sending data: the same as how you normally send data on http; http body, http form, query-string or header. Pick any. More generally: the question is "how do I [some already chosen, perhaps misadvised, implementation]?" - I'm saying you need to take a step back: "how do I [the thing I want to *achieve*]?". Comparison: "what is the best hammer for driving in screws?"

Comment: Sorry, I'm just frustrated because i cant find any help for these questions. I cant back track i have spent to much time on this project already, and have finished it, now i need to put the functionality into a [webmethod] if you follow the link you can see what i'm trying to Achieve :stackoverflow.com/q/10431928/1356321

Comment: I'm not really setup to repro that etc, but I would try it as a `byte[]` instead of a `Stream`. Are you familiar with `Stream` processing to fill the `byte[]` at the caller? Note also this will inevitably involve base-64, so will have a little overhead. To get back to a `Stream` at the receiver: `stream = new MemoryStream(theByteArray)`

Comment: ok so how do i Convert my stream into byte[]? and no i am unfamiliar to stream processing. so something like byte[] file = (FileUpload1.FileContent); and then pass it though?

Answer (score 2):

My advice is: forget `FileUpload` - just pass a `byte[]` and `string` (for the name, or whatever else you need). This should get handled as base-64 by the system.

From a `FileUpload` you should have access to the `.FileBytes` and `.FileName`, avoiding the need to mess with `Stream` etc.

At the receiving end (with a `byte[]` parameter), simply:

```
using(var stream = new MemoryStream(theByteArray)) {...}
```