# Is a Dataset the same as a Recordset

Tags: c#, vb.net, ado.net, dataset, recordset

I used to work in VB.net and used **Dataset's** all the time when working with ADO, but now i'm Working in C# and the Research is showing me a lot of **Recordsets**.

Are they the same thing?

If no what is the difference?

Comment: this would be so easy to google... http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20010920.asp or http://forums.asp.net/t/300189.aspx/1

Comment: Thanks for -1 me, i need 50 rep so i can bounty this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/10431928/1356321

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Datasets vs RecordSets](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/15809)

Essentially it is to do with how it fetches the data and allows you to intereact with it, recordsets would typically only allow you to fetch data from one table at a time (with default settings) whereas datasets can retrieve the entire set of data. there is more information at that link

> Dataset is a connectionless data holder whereas RecordSet is connection oriented Data holder.Though DataSet you can refer more than 1 table at a time, but in the case of Recordset only 1 table is processed at a time. Through Dataset you can process more than 1 record,but in case of recordset recordset you have to make travesel to each record and after that you can make processing.

a direct quote backing up what i said

Comment: Thanks :) Perfect answer :D, In your opinion is the one more beneficial then the other, Like can Dataset do every thing record set can?

Comment: i only have experience using datasets but i am very happy with how they perform. i havent yet found something i couldnt do with them that you could with any other database, i would imagine it can do the same thigns as they are both set out to be databases of a sort, they just handle how they operate differently but dont quote me on that!

Answer (score 1):

Difference between ADO.NET Dataset and ADO Recordset?

ADO.NET is an object-oriented set of libraries that allows you to interact with data sources.
http://www.job4india.in/interview-questions/net-interview-questions

ADO :-

1.It is a COM based library.
2.Classic ADO requires active connection with the data store.
3.Locking feature is available.
4.Data is stored in binary format.
5.XML integration is not possible.

ADO.NET :-

1.It is a CLR based library.
2.ADO.NET architecture works while the data store is disconnected.
3.Locking feature is not available.
4.Data is stored in XML.

Read More :- http://www.job4india.in/net-interview-questions/what-difference-between-ado-and-adonet

Answer (score 0):

No, the `DataSet` class (`System.Data` namespace) has the same name in C#. I'm not familiar with anything called recordset in ADO.NET (whereas I am with `DataSet`). Could you post some examples?

Comment: ADO.Net is not the same as classic ADO which the OP uses. Obviously ADO.net uses the .Net nomenclature...